# Clicking program tab on Taskbar in server 2003 brings two windows

Tags: taskbar, windows-server-2003

This is a crazy problem.

I am using server 2003 as my development machine.

When I click a "program icon" (Don't know if that is the right word) in the task bar, sometimes it will bring the program I clicked to along with another window.

The other "piggy back" window that is brought along is behind the window I clicked, but in front of all the other windows.

For example, I'm in outlook, and click an explorer window to see my file system. The explorer window will come to the front, but may bring my browser window with it, which is full screen. Now I have my browser covering outlook, with my explorer window on top of that.

This does not always happen, and the programs that get brought along are not consistent.

To make things worse, this seems to only happen after I have been in one application for a while (5 min) so it is not reproducible.

Comment: Have you tried using a different mouse? Sounds like the click mechanism is faulty. That, or the click sensitivity is set too high. Third option, which is unlikely if you're a developer, is that your mouse is moving during the click and it's registering as two separate clicks.